# Selling tokens with fees on Uniswap

Tags: 0x

I'm attempting to sell a token (0xC5a9BC46A7dbe1c6dE493E84A18f02E70E2c5A32) with fees (5% buy and sell) using the 0x: Exchange Proxy but the transaction fails with `Uniswap K`. This is the url I'm using to retrieve transaction data with 99% slippage:

https://api.0x.org/swap/v1/quote?sellToken=0xC5a9BC46A7dbe1c6dE493E84A18f02E70E2c5A32&buyToken=ETH&slippagePercentage=0.99&includedSources=Uniswap_V2%2CUniswap_V3&sellAmount=53646159623938

I found this in the documentation:

> Fee-on-transfer Tokens
> Some exotic tokens will take fees when any transfer of the token is performed. This often wreaks havoc on our settlement contracts as they are not aware of this mechanism and wind up attempting to sell less or receiving less than what the quote demands. In some circumstances you can buy these tokens by setting a high enough slippagePercentage to accommodate the transfer fee, but your mileage may vary.

Is it not possible to sell tokens with fees using 0x?

Answer (score 0):

ZRX API supports the ERC20 standard, if the token don't follows the standard it is not guaranted that the API will be able to give a quote, which is the case with fee on transfer tokens. Sometimes when set an higher slippage on the API these tokens are possible to trade, but it seems it is not your case.